# Search for model by multiple join record ids associated to model by has_many in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I have a product model setup like the following:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_atts, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :atts, :through => :product_atts
  has_many :variants, :class_name => "Product", :foreign_key => "parent_id", :dependent => :destroy
end
```

And I want to search for products that have associations with multiple attributes.

I thought maybe this would work:

```
Product.joins(:product_atts).where(parent_id: params[:product_id]).where(product_atts: {att_id: [5,7]})
```

But this does not seem to do what I am looking for.  This does where ID or ID.

So I tried the following:

```
Product.joins(:product_atts).where(parent_id: 3).where(product_atts: {att_id:  5}).where(product_atts: {att_id:  7})
```

But this doesn't work either, it returns 0 results.

So my question is how do I look for a model by passing in attributes of multiple join models of the same model type?

**SOLUTION:**

```
 att_ids = params[:att_ids] #This is an array of attribute ids
 product = Product.find(params[:product_id]) #This is the parent product
 scope = att_ids.reduce(product.variants) do |relation, att_id|
   relation.where('EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM product_atts WHERE product_id=products.id AND att_id=?)', att_id)
 end

 product_variant = scope.first
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a seemingly-simple request made actually pretty tricky by how SQL works. Joins are always just joining *rows* together, and your WHERE clauses are only going to be looking at *one* row at a time (hence why your expectations are not working like you expect -- it's not possible for one row to have two values for the same column.

There are a bunch of ways to solve this when dealing with raw SQL, but in Rails, I've found the simplest (not most efficient) way is to embed subqueries using the `EXISTS` keyword. Wrapping that up in a solution which handles arbitrary number of desired att_ids, you get:

```
scope = att_ids_to_find.reduce(Product) do |relation, att_id|
  relation.where('EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM product_atts WHERE parent_id=products.id AND att_id=?)', att_id)
end

products = scope.all
```

If you're not familiar with `reduce`, what's going on is it's taking `Product`, then adding one additional `where` clause for each att_id. The end result is something like `Product.where(...).where(...).where(...)`, but you don't need to worry about that too much. This solution also works well when mixed with scopes and other joins.

Comment: While I like that I am learning some new stuff here, the solution does not seem to work.  I replaced Product with product.variants, and att_ids_to_find = [6,11].  It is returning 0 results even though there is a product with both of those relations.

Comment: The resulting query is this: `SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."parent_id" = $1 AND (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM product_atts WHERE parent_id=products.id AND att_id=6)) AND (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM product_atts WHERE parent_id=products.id AND att_id=11))  [["parent_id", 3]]`

Comment: I just realized "parent_id" should be "product_id", whoops.

Comment: Awesome! The query and solution itself of course depend on your schema, which I was mostly guessing at; I'm glad you were able to find the full solution on your own.